# How to enable Virtual Guest Tagging(VGT) in ESXi 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, vlan, vmware-vcenter

I'm running ESXi 6.5 and managing the host using the built in http GUI.
Looking at documentation and videos on youtube on how to configure VLAN I only see them using the External vSphere Client and ESXi 6.0

Looking at the ESXi 6.5 http GUI the same selections are not available.
Basically I want to set up a portgroup on the vSwitch0 to be of type VGT so that the guest VM get's to handle the VLAN tagging itself.

The guest VM in this case is CoreOS in which I run docker, different docker networks are set up using macvlan (thereby creating sub interfaces with vlan specified in CoreOS).

Is these settings not available via the 6.5 web gui? Do I have to install vCenter Server?

References:
http://www.vmwarearena.com/vlan-tagging-vst-est-vgt-on-vmware/

See the following video, 4:53 minutes in:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zobxhWd7t4

See section 2 (Setting Up Networking with vSphere
Standard Switches):
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-65-networking-guide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a port group with VLAN 4095, which allows all VLANs.

Then, inside of your guest, configure the VLANs you need.

[image]

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable, but that also makes it limited to none(default VID), single(other than default VID) or all VIDS.

Comment: With the examples i referred to you could set multiple VID's, i.e 150-160, 172, 180-188.

Not that I currently need to set anything else than 4095 but still.

Guess the value set would corresponde to EST/VST/VGT as follows:
0 = None(EST), !0 = VST, 4095  = VGT